# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I got this error when trying to access a Service

The type 'WebRole1.RestServices.RegisterService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

This is linked to the definition on the Web.config file

I defined my service like this:

```
<!-- Service Authenticate -->
<service name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticationServiceBehaviors">
<endpoint contract="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
</service>

<!-- Service Register -->
<service name="WebRole1.RestServices.RegisterService" behaviorConfiguration="RegisterServiceBehaviors">
<endpoint contract="WebRole1.RestServices.IRegisterService" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
</service>
```

The definition working for the Authenticate Service but not for the Register Service.
I am not sure about the name i should put for the service but WebRole1.RestServices is the namespace for the RegisterService.svc

I am sure the error is from the Web.config file. Anyone has an idea how to correct this.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps from within Visual Studio:

1. Right click your service file
2. Select the `View Markup` option
3. Change the value of the `Service`
   attribute to reflect the fully
   qualified path of the underlying
   service type.
4. Make sure the `CodeFile` attribute value is also correct

This happens because when you rename the service type in code it doesn't automatically update the service mark-up directive values appropriately, or at all for that matter.

Comment: I updated it thanks <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebRole1.RestServices.RegisterService" CodeBehind="RegisterService.svc.cs" %>